# Toggle Class on Button click for multiples elements

Tags: javascript

I have a series of buttons that when clicked shows a box with options, but when i click on other button, the box keep visibile. How do I do when I click a button or outside the others boxes disappear?

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="popup-btn" data-itemid="1"> Button 1</button> 
    <input type="text" id="alvo-1" />
    <div id="popup-1" class="popup">
        <li data-alvo="1">item 1</li>
        <li data-alvo="1">item 2</li>
        <li data-alvo="1">item 3</li>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <button class="popup-btn" data-itemid="2"> Button 2</button>
    <input type="text" id="alvo-2" />
    <div id="popup-2" class="popup">
        <li data-alvo="2">item 1</li>
        <li data-alvo="2">item 2</li>
        <li data-alvo="2">item 3</li>
    </div>
</div>



.container{
  position: relative;
}
 .popup {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.popup.visible {
  display: block;
}




var button = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-btn")
var pop = document.querySelectorAll(".popup")
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li")



button.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let popup = document.getElementById("popup-" + event.target.dataset.itemid);
        popup.classList.toggle("visible");

  })
})


li.forEach(item => {
 item.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let alvo = document.getElementById("alvo-" + event.target.dataset.alvo);
        alvo.value = event.target.innerHTML

    let popup = item.parentNode;
        popup.classList.toggle("visible");

  })        
})
```

I tried to use forEach inside the button but it did not work

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tdxxcode/uen2gbkm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".popup-btn").forEach(item => {

  item.addEventListener('click', event => {

    /* Reset visible state of all popup lists to hidden */
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".popup")
      .forEach(popup => popup.classList.remove('visible'));

    /* Update visible state of sibling popup list (relative to clicked
    button) by selecting .popup from this buttons parent */
    const parentContainer = event
      .currentTarget
      .parentElement;

    const siblingPopup = parentContainer
      .querySelector('.popup');

    siblingPopup
      .classList
      .add("visible");
  })
});

/* Setup "hide" behavior when user clicks outside of a visible popup box */
document.querySelectorAll(".popup").forEach(popup => {
  popup.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target === popup) {
      popup
        .classList
        .remove("visible");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.popup.visible {
  display: block;
}

/* Create invisble region that triggers
the popup to hide when clicked */
.popup.visible:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="popup-btn"> Button 1</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul class="popup">
    <li data-alvo="1">item 1</li>
    <li data-alvo="1">item 2</li>
    <li data-alvo="1">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="popup-btn"> Button 2</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul class="popup">
    <li data-alvo="2">item 1</li>
    <li data-alvo="2">item 2</li>
    <li data-alvo="2">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this is to select the sibling popup (relative to the clicked button) via that buttons `parentElement`. A benefit of this is that it removes dependence on the custom `data` attribute (ie in your buttons markup).

Also, to achieve the hiding behaviour when the user clicks outside of the popup box, you could use a CSS pseudo element to "catch" user clicks that are outside of "inner content" the popup:

```
.popup.visible:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

The idea here is to define a temporary invisible element via CSS that is only present when the popup is visible. When clicked, this invisible element triggers a click event on the corresponding popup at which point you can determine if the popup should be hidden (ie if the popup matches the `event.target`):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".popup-btn").forEach(item => {

  item.addEventListener('click', event => {

    /* Reset visible state of all popup lists to hidden */
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".popup")
      .forEach(popup => popup.classList.remove('visible'));

    /* Update visible state of sibling popup list (relative to clicked
    button) by selecting .popup from this buttons parent */
    const parentContainer = event
      .currentTarget
      .parentElement;

    const siblingPopup = parentContainer
      .querySelector('.popup');

    siblingPopup
      .classList
      .add("visible");
  })
});

/* Setup "hide" behavior when user clicks outside of a visible popup box */
document.querySelectorAll(".popup").forEach(popup => {
  popup.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target === popup) {
      popup
        .classList
        .remove("visible");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.popup.visible {
  display: block;
}

/* Create invisble region that triggers
the popup to hide when clicked */
.popup.visible:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="popup-btn"> Button 1</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul class="popup">
    <li data-alvo="1">item 1</li>
    <li data-alvo="1">item 2</li>
    <li data-alvo="1">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="popup-btn"> Button 2</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul class="popup">
    <li data-alvo="2">item 1</li>
    <li data-alvo="2">item 2</li>
    <li data-alvo="2">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```